# Are there any major differences between Log4J 1.2 and Log4J 2.0?

Tags: configuration, log4j, slf4j

I'm curious about the differences between Log4J 1.2  and 2.0, because I've been trying to run a demo I found online ( [video here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6NhHDUCNQY) )  and I've run into issues. I was especially curious about what is the role of SLF4J in all of this, i.e do you need a certain SLF4J  for 1.2 vs 2.0 ?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIU from the [Apache Log4j 2 web site](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/), the significant is as the following: -

1. [The performance](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html) which compare among `log4j 1.x`, `logback` and `log4j 2`.
2. They provide 2 significant components as the following: -

   1. [SLF4J Binding](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html): The SLF4J bindings provided in this Bridge cause all the SLF4J APIs to be routed to Log4j 2.
   2. [Log4j 2 to SLF4J Adapter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-to-slf4j/index.html): The Log4j 2 to SLF4J Adapter allows applications coded to the Log4j 2 API to be routed to SLF4J.

Then we may use either the `SLF4J` as a Logging Facade with `log4j 2` instead of `logback` or use the `log4j 2` natively.

I hope this information may be useful.